# How do I mimic a recursive function model to an iterative one with a stack?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree

Let's consider the problem where I construct a Binary Search Tree from its inorder and postorder traversal. Now in the recursive implementation I would have done something like:

node.left = recursive (start, mid-1);
node.right = recursive (mid + 1, end);

Now how would I go about implementing this with a stack ? Cause once a node is popped from the stack I can't come back to it. Is this iterative approach only practical for a traversal ?

This is the gist of the whole code where _constructInPost is recursive:

```
Node<T> _constructInPost (List<T> in, List<T> post) {

    if (in.size() == 0)
        return null;

    Node<T> root = new Node <T>(post.get(post.size()-1));

    int index = 0;
    for ( ; index < post.size(); index++) {
        if (in.get(index) == root.data) 
            break;
    }

    root.left = _constructInPost (in.subList(0, index), post.subList(0, index));
    root.right = _constructInPost (in.subList(index+1, in.size()), post.subList(index, post.size()-1));

    return root;
}
```

Comment: you can always substitute recursion with iteration because that's what the operating system is doing in the background, what's your whole code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, "Learn Forth." :-)

Your stack will contain instructions about what to do.  So if you want 2 recursive calls, you will place 2 commands on the stack.  If you have work to do, you will do that work.  If you want to do 2 recursive calls and then other stuff with the result, you need to place on your stack instructions to do other stuff, then the recursive calls.  (That way you don't get to the other stuff until after the recursion happens.)  Your basic loop then has the following pattern:

```
while stack.length():
    command = stack.pop()
    if command.name == 'recursive_call':
        do recursive code that may add to the stack
    elif command.name == 'base case':
        do base case
```

Comment: So I'm better off doing a recursion then, cause in effect we are implementing a function stack here. Am I right?

Comment: @shrinidhisondur yes that's how changing from recursive to iterative implementation works in general case, you do what the operating system would do for you (creating the function call stack, in some cases you can save some memory/time though)

Comment: In practice you are better off doing recursion.  But you're better off *understanding* this approach as well.  Because if you only understand recursion, the simple challenge to convert a depth-first search into a breadth-first one is impossible.  If you understand this approach, then you can just say, "Replace a stack with a queue" and you're most of the way there.